# Grails Difference between <g:message code=""/> and ${message(code)}

Tags: grails

In Grails there are two (main) ways to insert an internationalized string into a gsp:

```
<g:message code="your.code.here" />
```

and

```
 ${message(code:'your.code.here')}
```

I thought that I saw at one point that the first one above is recommended when in the middle of HTML code

```
<h1><g:message code="title.header.text" /></h1>
```

and the second one above is recommended when in JavaScript code (with quotes around it) like

```
var messageToDisplay = "${message(code:'your.code.here')}";
```

However, I have also seen people do

```
<h1>${message(code:'title.header.text')}</h1>
```

Is this last line below also acceptable/recommended in Grails?
Is there a reason to do/not do the last option above?

(Edit added below)

One other question about encoding:
In the middle of HTML it is (sometimes) necessary to do

```
<h1><g:message code="title.header.text" encodeAs="HTML"/></h1>
```

And in the middle of JavaScript

```
var messageToDisplay = "${message(code:'your.code.here').encodeAsJavaScript()}";
```

Then is there a difference?  Can the default encoding be changed to HTML for a Tag and to JavaScript for the ${message(code)}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all perfectly valid. It all depends on context and style. Most people prefer to use the tags when possible. They all, ultimately, use the same tag library/code.

The `message(code:)` format is particularly useful when you need to resolve messages within a controller, other tag library, or service.

Answer (score 0):

Tags and scriptlets are the same thing underneath but my preference is to use tags where possible in web pages as they fit better with the rest of the HTML markup and are a little easier to read.